# PHP explode removes 0 sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: php

I'm using PHP and its explode function.

```
list($n, $dec) = explode(".", 79.4833581718827620);
```

After that $dec is 4833581718827620 as I want, so this is OK.

```
list($n, $dec) = explode(".", 1.10);
```

After that $dec is 1 instead of 10.

Why is $dec 1 instead of 10?

Comment: explode is a string function `list($n, $dec) = explode(".", "1.10");` works

Comment: `79.4833581718827620` and `1.10` are read as numeric values and it's interpreted as `79.483358171882762` and `1.1` even before explode function runs, so you should define it as a string, as @rtfm suggested, to get 0 at the end

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you for your help.